# How to apply the same transformation on all commits in a sequence without manually going through each?

Tags: git

Let say i have following Git scenario, where:

- On `1st` Commit: I create `lorem/text01.txt` with some random text inside `text01.txt`
- On `2nd` Commit: I create `lorem/text02.txt` with some random text inside `text02.txt`
- On `3rd` Commit: I create `lorem/text03.txt` with some random text inside `text03.txt`
- On `4th` Commit: I create `lorem/text04.txt` with some random text inside `text04.txt`

and so on... (you know the pattern already)

**after** let say on `1001th` commit you notice that all those files (`text01.txt`....`text1001.txt`) **should be inside** `newfoldername/` **not** inside `lorem/`,

**but the problem is** you don't want to just create `newfoldername/`, move all those files on new directory, and then commit it.

You want your **Git History to look nice** since the beginning, **i.e** `1st` commit to be about creating `newfoldername/text01.txt`, `2nd` commit to be about creating `newfoldername/text02.txt` and so on.

**So my question is**, how to achieve this without having to **rebase (`git rebase -i`)** each commit sequence individually?

Answer (score 2):

[`git-filter-branch`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html):

> Lets you rewrite Git revision history by rewriting the branches mentioned in the , applying custom filters on each revision. Those filters can modify each tree (e.g. removing a file or running a perl rewrite on all files) or information about each commit. Otherwise, all information (including original commit times or merge information) will be preserved.

Comment: I already did the following `git filter-branch --tree-filter "mv lorem\ newfoldername\" HEAD`, but it returns following error:

`Rewrite 28db94b1bad4f3f787551e521053f38a48284971 (1/586) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)

C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-branch: eval: line 401: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`"'

C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-branch: eval: line 402: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @xcode, this can be easily explained if you run this command in Git Bash: the first " starts grouping the following characters (to form a single string to send as an argument to `--tree-filter`) up to, but not including, the next _unescaped_ " character. In Unix-style shells a backslash character, `\` escapes the immediately following character. In your encantation the backslash at the end of the `newfoldername` is treated by Git Bash as escaping the following `"`. The end result is an unterminated double quoted string, which is what gets reported to you.

Comment: @xcode, when working in Git bash, use the "normal" forward slashes, `/`, as path separators. (Note that they work in most places even with native Windows commands as internally Windows has no problems using `/` as path separators.)

Comment: but if i run `git filter-branch --tree-filter "mv lorem/ newfoldername/" HEAD` it would give an error:

`Rewrite 28db94b1bad4f3f787551e521053f38a48284971 (1/586) (1 seconds passed, remaining 585 predicted)    mv: cannot stat 'lorem/': No such file or directory
tree filter failed: mv lorem/ newfoldername/`

Comment: i dont know i still got confused on how this `filter-branch` work, couldn't wrap my head around it.